# Can I download all my received emails?

Tags: email, imap, domain, hosting, pop3

So, basically, what I want to somehow download all the emails that I have ever received. My email address is a custom one that I created on my own domain (that I bought from a hosting company).

Is that even possible? The email client I am using has emails only some months old.

Comment: Are you using IMAP, POP3 or a Web-Interface to access your mails?

Comment: IMAP for Apple Mail but I also have web interface (roundcube) access to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can offline your all mails. As you haven't specified your client, here how to do it :

ThunderBird (I love it!) :
  http://www.seas.upenn.edu/cets/answers/thunderbird-offline.html

Outlook:
  http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/force-outlook-2007-to-download-complete-imap-items/

Comment: I am using Apple Mail and what I want to do exactly is to download all the mails from the server.

Comment: I haven't used Apple Mail yet. Still a search resulted in http://homepage.mac.com/aamann/Mail_Scripts.html & http://www.hawkwings.net/plugins.htm - plugins to archive mailboxes on you system. If that fails there is thunderbird for Mac, try it.